# Replace version in yaml structure with regexp

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'm trying to replace the value of the version property in the following yaml structure.

My reason for using regex rather than parsing the yaml is that I need to write it back again. If I parse it and then write it back it'll loose it's existing formatting.

```
environments:
  local:
    values:
      - kubeContext: default
      - surfScreenshotter:
          installed: false
          version: 0
      - whoamiMn:
          installed: false
          version: 0
  dev:
    values:
      - kubeContext: nuc
      - surfScreenshotter:
          installed: false
          version: 0
      - whoamiMn:
          installed: false
          version: 0
```

My kotlin code

```
val regex = """environments:
    |.*
    |  $environment:
    |    values:
    |.*
    |      - $projectName:
    |.*
    | {10}version: (\S+)
""".trimMargin().toRegex(MULTILINE)
val updatedHelmfile = regex.replaceFirst(helmfileContent, version)
```

$environment can be either "local" or "dev" and projectName can be "surfScreenshotter" or "whoamiMn".

Nothing is matched. Anyone got an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on indentation to make sure you are in the right section of your text block and capture the whole part before the version into a capturing group:

```kotlin
val regex = """(environments:
    |(?:\R\h{2}.*)*?\R\h{2}$environment:
    |(?:\R\h{4}.*)*?\R\h{6}-\h*$projectName:
    |(?:\R\h{10}.*)*?\R\h{10}
    |version:\h*)\S+
""".trimMargin().toRegex(RegexOption.COMMENTS)
```

Then, you need to make sure to restore Group 1 contents with `$1` in the replacement pattern:

```
val updatedHelmfile = regex.replaceFirst(helmfileContent, "$1" + version)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lGbZBt/1/) and the  [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/X1dXS5).

**Details**

- `(environments:` - Group 1 start and `environments:` string
- `(?:\R\h{2}.*)*?\R\h{2}dev:` - zero or more occurrences (as few as possible) of a line break followed with two horizontal whitespace and then the rest of the line, then a line break, two horizontal whitespace and `dev:` string
- `(?:\R\h{4}.*)*?\R\h{6}-\h*whoamiMn:` - zero or more occurrences (as few as possible) of a line break followed with four horizontal whitespace and then the rest of the line, then a line break, six horizontal whitespace and `-` + 0 or more spaces, and then `whoamiMn:` string
- `(?:\R\h{10}.*)*?\R\h{10}` - zero or more occurrences (as few as possible) of a line break followed with ten horizontal whitespace and then the rest of the line, then a line break, ten horizontal whitespace
- `version:\h*)` - `version:`, 0 or more spaces, end of Group 1
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.